# Getting cannot resolve symbol 'mContext' when I use context as a parameter in java class in android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this java class in kotlin:

```
class SessionManager (context: Context) {
    private var prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    
    companion object {
        const val USER_TOKEN = "user_token"
    }

    /**
     * Function to save auth token
     */
    fun saveAuthToken(token: String) {
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putString(USER_TOKEN, token)
        editor.apply()
    }

    /**
     * Function to fetch auth token
     */
    fun fetchAuthToken(): String? {
        return prefs.getString(USER_TOKEN, null)
    }
}
```

And I want to make it in java. I have done it like this, but I´m getting an error with the context:

```
public class SessionManager(Context mContext){



    SharedPreferences preferencias=mContext.getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    public void saveAuthToken(String token){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferencias.edit();
        editor.putString("user_token",token);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String fetchAuthToken() {
        return preferencias.getString("user_token", null);
    }
}
```

I get  Cannot resolve symbol 'mContext' and I don´t know why.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you have to create constructors explicitly:

```java
public class SessionManager {
   SharedPreferences preferencias;
   public SessionManager(Context mContext) {
      preferencias=mContext.getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   }
...
}
```